# Probability of Rolled Dice

Tags: probability

10 dice are rolled. I need to determine the probability of the following:

1. Probability at least 1 dice roll lands on a 3
2. Probability the first dice has a 3 and none of the other rolls are a 3
3. Probability the last dice has a 3 and none of the other rolls are a 3
4. Exactly one roll is a 3

I've determined all answers except for 1.

For 2 and 3, I got (1/6) * $({5/6})^9$

For 4, I got (1/6) * $({5/6})^9$ * (10 Choose 1)

Please lend me some help for 1.

Comment: The complementary event is that no dice land on a $3$

Comment: So the answer will be 1 - (5/6)^10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to part 1 is $1-(5/6)$<sup>10</sup>

let event A = event in which at least one die rolls 3
let event B = event in which none of the dice roll three

clearly, $A ∩ B = ɸ$
thus $P(A) + P(B) = 1$

making $P(A) = 1 - P(B)$

but we know that $P(B) =(5/6)$<sup>10</sup>

Hence $P(A) = 1 - (5/6)$<sup>10</sup>

Comment: to understand why A and B are disjoint, understand that A basically  means that either one 3 or two 3s or three 3s or 4 3s...…..or ten 3s . whereas B means zero threes. clearly whenever dice are rolled any one of A or B has to happen. both cant happen simultaneously